# How to set the CPU priority (niceness) of a Docker container?

Tags: docker

One of my containers is always busy, and is taking CPU away from other containers (webservers) that need to be responsive and are only active from time to time.

I would like to lower the CPU priority of the CPU-consuming container, so that whenever the other containers need the CPU, it is not clogged.

How do I do this? I have been searching the web for a while now, but I can't find the answer.

I have tried running the container with `--entrypoint='nice 10 mybinary'`, but it turns out `--entrypoint` can only run binaries, not shell commands.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can limit CPU resources on the container level. I recommend to use `--cpu-shares 512` for your case.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/:

> Set this flag to a value greater or less than the default of 1024 to increase or reduce the container’s weight, and give it access to a greater or lesser proportion of the host machine’s CPU cycles. This is only enforced when CPU cycles are constrained. When plenty of CPU cycles are available, all containers use as much CPU as they need. In that way, this is a soft limit. --cpu-shares does not prevent containers from being scheduled in swarm mode. It prioritizes container CPU resources for the available CPU cycles. It does not guarantee or reserve any specific CPU access.

Comment: Why do you recommend 512?

Comment: @kovan best description I could find: https://engineering.squarespace.com/blog/2017/understanding-linux-container-scheduling#cpu-shares
Every cgroup (e.g. all containers) compete for CPU resources. If all CPU resources are utilized, you can provide one higher priority. Having 3 tasks with 1024, 1024 and 2048 will create a 1:1:2 ratio. 1024 is the default. So if CPU is rare, the process with a smaller number will receive less CPU time. But the system doesn't pause it. These three processes will (if all require CPU time) 25%/25%/50% of the available CPU.

Answer (score 3):

`--cpu-shares` looks like a good answer, although it's not clear to me how to verify it's working.  I'm also curious what the max value is?  Document doesn't say.

But, as an alternative for trusted containers, that [same document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) also shows `--cap-add=sys_nice` that will allow changing process priorities within a container.  i.e., if the `nice` or `renice` command is available within the container, it should work when you add the `sys_nice` capability.  You'll only want to allow this capability for trusted containers because you don't want untrusted programs changing their own priorities willy nilly.

You can verify by inspecting the `NI` column for the process in question using `top` or `ps -efl` on the host.

Comment: The `SYS_NICE` capability is only required for decreasing niceness, i.e. increasing the priority. So for lowering the priority of processes with `nice` or `renice` it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the CPU shares is the most direct answer to your request, and typically preferred over adding capabilities to the container could be used by a malicious actor inside of the container to impact the host. The only reason I can think of to add the SYS_NICE capability to the container is if you have multiple processes inside the container and want to give different priorities to them, or need to change the priority while the container is running.

The more traditional solution to noisy neighbors is to configure each container with a limit on how much CPU and memory it is allowed to use. This is an upper bound, so realize there may be idle CPU resources if you set this low and do not have any other tasks available for the CPU to run.

The easiest way to set the limit on containers from the `docker run` command line is with `--cpus` which allows you to configure a fractional number of cores to be available to the container. Passing an option like `--cpus 2.5` allows the container to use as many as 2.5 cores before the kernel scheduler throttles the process. If you had a 4 core host, that would ensure that at least 1.5 cores are always available to other processes.

Related to these limits, with Swarm Mode you can also configure a reservation for CPU (and memory). The reservation is a lower limit that Docker ensures has not been reserved for any other containers. This is used to select nodes to schedule containers, and may prevent some containers from being scheduled when there are not enough resources available, rather than scheduling so many jobs on a single node that it fails.